# CSS bottom bar isn't correctly shown with chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a bar on the bottom of my webpage and the code is the following:

```
<div class="casa5">
<label style="margin:auto;"><font color="orange">&#9733;</font> my text <font color="orange">&#9733;</font></label>
</div>
```

And here you can see the CSS:

```
.casa5 {
 background-color:#0C0C0C;
 width:100%;
 height:24px;
 position:absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align:center;
 font: 90% 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#E8E8E8;
}
```

This `div` is displayed in the bottom of the page as you can see here:

[image]

I am using firefox. By the way I am in trouble because when I open the page with Chrome, I have this view:

[image]

As you can see, when you open the page with Firefox, the bar lies on the bottom of the page, but when I load the same page with Chrome, where is a gap between my div and the bottom.

I want the bar to be displayed on the bottom of the page only when I scroll down until the end. How could I fix this?

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, remove the `font` tags. It is no longer 1998.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You just need to add `bottom: 0` to your css:

  ```
  .casa5 {
      background-color:#0C0C0C;
      width:100%;
      height:24px;
      position:absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align:center;
      font: 90%'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color:#E8E8E8;
      bottom: 0;
  }
  ```

  Also, you should probably change `position:absolute;` to `position: fixed;` for it to always be at the bottom whether the user scrolls or not.

  <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7f2v/1/)</kbd>
- However, if you would like for it to always be at the end of the page, you can do something like this:

  ```
  html {
      position: relative;
  }
  .casa5 {
      background-color:#0C0C0C;
      width:100%;
      height:24px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align:center;
      font: 90%'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color:#E8E8E8;
      bottom: 0;
  }
  ```

  It changes the `html` to `position: relative` and keeps the footer at `position: absolute`

  <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7f2v/2/)</kbd>

  As suggested by http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: But the bar must be at the end of the page, this means that when I scroll down, I see it at the end.

Comment: Yes, it should stay at the bottom of the page always if that's what you mean.

Comment: You almost got it. In your fiddle the numbers goes below the bar when I scroll the page. I want the bar to be displayed only when I arrive at the end of the page. Do you understand what I need?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  The best I could think of would be to place it at the end of the code but obviously that causes issues.  But this website seems to be useful for what you are thinking of http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I also just found out a better way to do it than that link and posted it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `bottom: 0;` to your CSS.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gzX7y/